# Как сделать запрос в MySQL для подсчета возвращаемости клиентов?

Tags: mysql

Имеется две таблицы:
Первая

```
CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=26 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

Вторая

```
CREATE TABLE `window` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `master_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `status` tinyint(3) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=218 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

Мне нужно посчитать возвращаемость клиентов на текущий месяц в сравнении с предыдущим месяцем. Формула примерно следующая (ИМХО): ***(∑(Кол-во записей user_id в пред месяц)/∑(Кол-во записей user_id в текущий месяц))***. Вполне возможно формулу можно упростить до ***(∑(Кол-во записей в пред месяц)/∑(Кол-во записей в текущий месяц КРОМЕ записей новых пользователей))***.

На данный момент я написал примерно следующее:

```
SELECT (SELECT count(*) FROM `window`
   WHERE date>=DATE_FORMAT(LAST_DAY(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH), '%Y-%m-%d 23:59:59'))/
   (SELECT count(*) FROM `window`
   WHERE date<=DATE_FORMAT(LAST_DAY(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH), '%Y-%m-%d 23:59:59')
   AND date>=DATE_FORMAT(LAST_DAY(NOW() - INTERVAL 2 MONTH), '%Y-%m-%d 23:59:59'));
```

Но я не знаю как тут сделать исключение на записи новых пользователей и те ли цифры он выдает в принципе.

Comment: *Формула примерно следующая* Вот это и проблема. Пока "приблизительно" не уйдёт из формулировки, дальше двигаться (писать запрос) бессмысленно.

Comment: Составляя формулировку оперируй такими сведениями: клиент был до предыдущего месяца, клиент появился в предыдущем месяце, клиент появился в этом месяце. Соответственно первый может быть или не быть в прошлом и/или в этом, второй быть или нет в этом. Соотношение каких- то двух величин (отдельно или сумма) и есть нужный показатель.

Comment: @Akina, "Примерно" в данном контексте было использовано постольку, поскольку показатель "Возвращаемость клиентов" не является точным показателем. Это зависит от особенностей услуг предоставляемых компанией/фирмой/лицом. И от этих особенностей меняется рассматриваемый промежуток времени. Здесь я использую один месяц, хотя в дальнейшем это может изменится.

Comment: Точное определение алгоритма не связано с продолжительностью периода. Текущий и предыдущий периоды - а кто из них сколько, то пофиг, включая и равность их продолжительности.

Comment: Для запроса текущего месяца вам нужно поставить условие `WHERE user_id IN (SELECT user_id запрос предыдущего месяца)`